# How to call a function of a OpenERP class through openerplib or xmlrpclib?

Tags: python, controller, odoo, openerp-7, xmlrpclib

I'm trying to call a function declared in the class `res.partner` from a controller. This controller is "outside", so I had to use `openerplib` (`xmlrpclib` is also valid) to get data from the models.

For example:

```
connection = openerplib.get_connection (hostname="localhost", database="my_db", login="admin", password="my_pwd", port=8069)     
res_partner_model = connection.get_model("res.partner")
```

Now I have the model and I can use `search`, `read`, or `search_read` methods to get data from the `res.partner` model.

But, how can I call a function declared in that class? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call function using `xmlrpclib`.

Try this,

```
import xmlrpclib

#dbname = "my_db"
#username = "admin"
#pwd = "my_pwd"

sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
#uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
uid = sock_common.login("my_db", "admin", "my_pwd")
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

#this will search all ids of res_partner class
partner_ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'search',[])

for partner_id in partner_ids:
    #res = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'your_function_name', [partner_id])
    res = sock.execute("my_db", uid, "my_pwd", 'res.partner', 'your_function_name', [partner_id])
    print '\n====res=====',res

print " Ending Query ... "
```